# Multiple React effect hooks for the same dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

Let's say I have an effect hook with a `Person` dependency that follows the schema `Person: {name: string, age: number}`. My effect hook for this `Person` dependency currently looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (person.name === 'Mike') {
    doSomething()
  }

  if (person.age > 21) {
    somethingElse()
  }
}, [person])
```

Would it be valid code to separate this logic into their own effect hooks with the same dependencies:

```
// effect that handles any logic for a person's name
useEffect(() => {
  if (person.name === 'Mike') {
    doSomething()
  }
}, [person])

// effect that handles any logic for a person's age
useEffect(() => {
  if (person.age > 21) {
    somethingElse()
  }
}, [person])
```

I'm trying to separate unrelated code from each other in some of my components, and I'm wondering if this would be considered an anti-pattern or if it could result in unwanted issues?

Comment: no, that's fine.

Comment: Side note: you could specify the object properties as dependencies instead of the entire object. E.g. `[person.name]` and `[person.age]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. Although, I would check person properties on each individual effect call separately. Check the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) for a good example. ( I really dislike when others are answering and I'm still typing...)

```
 // effect that handles any logic for a person's name
useEffect(() => {
  if (person.name === 'Mike') {
    doSomething()
  }
}, [person.name])

// effect that handles any logic for a person's age
useEffect(() => {
  if (person.age > 21) {
    somethingElse()
  }
}, [person.age])
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is acceptable to write code in this fashion, you might want to run the effects on what they're actually concerned with. ie

```
// effect that handles any logic for a person's name
useEffect(() => {
  if (person.name === 'Mike') {
    doSomething()
  }
}, [person.name])

// effect that handles any logic for a person's age
useEffect(() => {
  if (person.age > 21) {
    somethingElse()
  }
}, [person.age])
```